# Microsoft Access VBA: Button to Filter Report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have created a report in Microsoft Access, which provides users with data including identification number, locations, notes, etc. stored in a data table called Report Data. When I click to open the report, it will load all 2000+ 1 page reports (1 Per IDENT NO). However, I want only the 1 report the user selects by entering the IDENT NO to be loaded/displayed.

I have created a button with the following code below, which I want to filter my reports by IDENT NO entered by a user when clicked (When the user clicks the button, a pop-up will ask for the IDENT NO, and then I want to only open the single report associated with that IDENT NO). However when I do so, it will load only the 1 page report like I want it to do, however none of the other data fields are filled in. I have been playing around with the code for a while now, but I can't seem to figure out if the issue is based on the code below, or due to another issue.

For Reference, the identification numbers take the form of a number with a dash and then a version like so: 1940-1 or 1940-2 or 2910-1 are all examples of identification numbers.

```
Private Sub Command33_Click()

Dim id As String
    id = InputBox("Enter the identification number:", "Report Filter")

'if a value was entered, open and filter report
If Len(Trim(id)) > 0 Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport "RARL Requests Report", acViewPreview, , "[IDENT NO] like " & id, acWindowNormal
End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ID 'numbers' are text values. So the ID field is a text type. Filter parameters for a text field require apostrophe delimiters. Using LIKE operator without * wildcard accomplishes nothing more than using = sign.

`DoCmd.OpenReport "RARL Requests Report", acViewPreview, , "[IDENT NO] = '" & id & "'", acWindowNormal`

I did a test with and without apostrophes. Without I got two popup input prompts, with apostrophes only the InputBox popped up. However, in both cases the report still opened filtered and with data. So something else may be going on with your issue. Might require direct review of your db. If you want to provide, can upload to a fileshare site such as Box.com and post link to the file.

Hard to validate InputBox entry. The report runs even if the entry is not valid causing frustration for user. Would be better to use a combobox on a form for user selection of ID.

Advise no spaces or punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in names.

Comment: Is it possible to modify the above so that it would open any reports that begin with what the user entered. So for example if I had reports with IDENT NO's 1940-1, 1940-2 and 1940-3 and the user only entered 1940 into the InputBox, it would display all 3 of those reports?

Comment: `"[IDENT NO] LIKE '" & id & "*'"` - A combobox would still be my recommended approach. Just set to not restrict input to listed values. But the list would still be there to guide users for valid complete ID numbers.

Comment: I see what you are getting at. Is there a combobox function that I can replace the InputBox with in that line of code such that I still click the button to open up the combo box selection? Also if this is the case, does the remainder of the code require additional modification?

Comment: Name combobox something like cbxID, then: `"[IDENT NO] LIKE '" & Me.cbxID & "*'"`

Comment: Alright. Is it possible to generate the combobox from the code though. something like cbxID = ComboBox(Fields), in the place of id = InputBox (Fields) or is this not possible in Access?

Comment: A combobox is a control on a form. So no, what you described is not intrinsically possible in Access.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your IdentNo is a text field.  You need to scope it with single quotes.  So:

```
If Len(Trim(id)) > 0 Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport "RARL Requests Report", acViewPreview, , "[IDENT NO] like '" & id & "'", acWindowNormal
End If
```

If it were not text (i.e. Int or Double) then you would do it the way you had it; no single quotes needed.